# trying to build hello world but im getting an error and its not building it correctly

Tags: codelite

so im using codelite for my schooling purposes and the first issue that im running into is that it is not building it correctly i get this string of code in the result box.

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 -e -f  Makefile
'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
=== build completed successfully (0 errors, 0 warnings) ===

I've checked the initial commands and they are typed correctly. please help thanks.

I've tried rewriting the hello world code 2x I've checked the breakthroughs and ive even tried disabling them. they are back on now. I've downloaded another debugger and that did nothing as well.

Comment: Hi @nox, no offence but did you install a C++ compiler? CodeLite only provides the graphical tools for development. I've had to do this so often that I know what a pain it is. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319017/1793968) helps? If you want then I'm happy to send a ZIP file containing CodeLite, a compiler and wxWidgets.