# CodeLite and wxWidgets on Windows: build completes successfully but program crashes

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, wxwidgets, codelite

On a Windows 7 virtual machine I set up a C++ build environment using the following:

1. `C:\usr\local\gcc-13.2.0` (from winlibs);
2. `C:\usr\local\cmake-3.27.6` (from KitWare);
3. `C:\usr\local\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1` (sources, from wxwidgets.org);
4. `C:\usr\local\codelite-17.6.0` (from codelite.org),
   built wxWidgets in the directory `C:\usr\local\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\build` (directory was there already, seemed the right place), using the `CMake` and `gcc` executables above and using `mingw32-make` from the compiler directory.

The binaries are in `lib\gcc_x64_dll` under the wxWidgets directory, and the names of all the shared libraries end in `_gcc_custom.dll`.

Then to build a wxWidgets 'Hello World' example, in CodeLite:

1. changed "Settings" - "Compiler Settings" to the just-installed `gcc`
2. changed "Settings" - "GDB Settings" to `gdb` in the same directory
3. added `WXWIN=C:\usr\local\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1` and `WXCFG=gcc_x64_dll\mswu` to "Settings" -> "Environment Variables"
4. open a new project "hello_wxwidget", Category "GUI", Type "wxWidgets GUI application", compiler and debugger as above, Build System "CodeLite Makefile Generator". This will generate standard code to make a simple wxFrame.

The program builds successfully! However, when I run it, the output in CodeLite is just "Program exited" (no error messages) and no window appears.

When I run it through the debugger, it says `Debugger exited with the following error string: "During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135`".

Without other errors and warnings and no call stack available, is it possible to find out what is not working here?

EDIT

Following advice by @Tsyvarev I have opened the `.exe` file in the program [Explorer Suite](https://ntcore.com/files/ExplorerSuite.exe), which shows its dependencies:

1. `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`,
2. `libstdc++-6.dll` (both in `C:\usr\local\gcc-13.2.0\bin` but not found by CFF Explorer);
3. `KERNEL32.dll`,
4. `ucrtbase.dll` (both found in `C:\Windows\system32`);
5. `wxbase32u_gcc_custom.dll`,
6. `wxmsw32u_core_gcc_custom.dll`,
7. `wxmsw32u_xrc_gcc_custom.dll` (all three in `C:\usr\local\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libgcc_x64_dll` but not found by CFF Explorer)

In my "Settings" -> "Global Settings" I have now added `C:\usr\local\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\gcc_x64_dll; C:\usr\local\gcc-13.2.0\bin;` to the "Library Path" and `-lwxbase32u_gcc_custom; -lwxmsw32u_core_gcc_custom; -lwxmsw32u_xrc_gcc_custom; -llibgcc_s_seh-1; -llibstdc++-6` to the "Linker Options". To make the last option work I also need to rename `libstdc++-6.dll.a` in the compiler's `lib` directory, otherwise the `.a` clashes with the `.so`.

Compilation finishes successfully, program crashes. From the IDE as well as from the shell. The IDE (debugger) gives the "exit code" message and the shell says: "The program cannot start because libgcc_s_seh-1.dll is missing from your computer."

Does anyone know what is needed to be able to use those DLLs both during linking my program and for running it independently?

EDIT II

After putting the two directories `C:\usr\local\gcc-13.2.0\bin` (the DLLs of g++) and `C:\usr\local\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\gcc_x64_dll` (the DLLs of wxWidgets) to the path and restarting:

1. the first run from the IDE neither produced an error, nor a window
2. the first run from the shell produced a window (!)
3. all runs after that from the IDE produced a window as well

So that finally seems to have done the trick! (though not really sure what happened at "1.")

Will do some more testing and then produce a nice bullet list.

Comment: The error `0xc0000135` is about not finding some of dll, which is needed for your program. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency) about resolving all dlls for the program.

Comment: Interesting thanks! Will try. I had expected that missing DLLs would lead to 'undefined reference' messages in the IDE?

Comment: The error `undefined reference` is emitted at **link time**, when the linker cannot find definition of the symbol (function). The error code `0xc0000135` is emitted at **runtime**, when the loader failed to find some dll.

Comment: OK thanks! Now if I open the .exe file in `build-Debug` with CFF Explorer, I get a list of 7 DLLs, which i have added in the post. I'm not really sure what I should change in my project to successfully build and run it though! Or do I need to set the DLL path globally?

Comment: @alle_meije, did you build wxWidgets yourself? If not - I suggest downloading the source code and build it using the option to static linking the library, e.g. `cd wxWidgets-X.Y.Z\build\msw && mingw32-bin.exe -f makefile.gcc BUILD=Debug SHARED=0`. Then re-create the project inside CodeLite to use the statically linked wxWidgets.

Comment: I built it myself with GCC for Windows and CMake, as dynamic libraries (see 1st paragraph). I use DLLs all the time for console applications, I don't see how it wouldn't be possible for making windowed applications?

Comment: @alle_meije, it is. But when you buuild as DLL you have to make the DLL available during the Run-Time. Whereas when you build statically everything is built-in. Now for the CRT it is strongly recommended to build dynamically, so any updates to the Windows itself will just pick up the DLLs. But wxWidgets can be built statically and therefore will not need to be copied, shipped or distributed in any way - everything wil be inside the binary.

Comment: For 8nix/OSX - its a different story. On those systems everything is dynamic. Which makes it very easy to update any of the packages or even have it side-by-side.

Comment: So my suggestion is to use `SHARED=0` when building wxWidgets and then use appropriate option when building you application. Then you will need only CRT and MinGW libraries with you binaries.

Comment: Thanks @Igor for the suggestion! I come from a Linux background so I am more used to shared libraries. In linux building this example is a lot easier, but I would like to show this to windows users as well. You are completely right - after putting the DLLs of wxWidgets and of the compiler in the path, everything runs smoothly! I thought it was quite tricky to find the documentation on this though...

Comment: @alle_meije, I totally understand. The de-facto standard is on Windows to build statically, unless you are creating a DLL yourself. Then it is suggested to build dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the comments by @Tsyvarev and @Igor helped me find the answer. The issue with building wxWidgets as shared libraries, which is normal in Linux but not in Windows, is that these libraries need to be in the system's (or the user's) `Path` environment variable. They could also be copied into every executable's directory, but that would defy the purpose of shared libraries!

So my recipe for building GUIs with wxWidgets in CodeLite in Windows is:

1. Download G++, CMake and CodeLite binaries and wxWidgets sources;
2. Build wxWidgets with GCC and CMake (with wxBUILD_SHARED ticked);
3. Set the compiler in CodeLite to the new GCC and set `WXWIN` and `WXCFG` to the wxWidgets source directory and the lib//mswu directory, respectively;
4. Set the System `Path` environment variable so that it includes both the `bin` directory of the GCC compiler and the full path of the `WXCFG` directory's parent;
5. Select a project type in CodeLite that is wxWidgets-aware: it will put the right compiler, linker and resources options in.

In the end, no extra linker options are necessary for building, but if you want to use shared libraries as they were intended, they need to be reachable via the `Path` environment variable (there is no `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` equivalent)

I copied the result of steps 1-2 to another Windows 7 virtual machine and steps 3-5 were enough to get a wxFrame working.

Comment: keep in mind that wxWidgets have the Makefile to build it with gcc. CMake build make sense when it is part of the bigger project which is huge.

Comment: But for testing all you do is `cd wxWidgets\build\msw && mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=Debug SHARED =0`. And then when you are ready to distribute - you try CMake.

Comment: Yes sorry, this recipe is for the very stubborn who think it's silly not to use shared libraries :)